# Extract only numbers from text

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, pattern-matching, match

I'm trying to extract only numbers from a string/text. Below is the regex pattern I'm using.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\d+]\S+");
string extract_from = " 12 abcd 1-2-3a a123z 1.2.3.4 xyz";
```

From the string "extract_from" above, the regex is extracting the numbers

```
12
1-2-3a
123z
1.2.3.4
```

The regex is extracting it correctly except the second and third one "1-2-3a", "123z", which shouldn't be extracted because it contains an alphabet. What pattern can I add in regex to not extract where the numbers also have an alphabet in between?

dash and dot are ok, just not alphabets.

Comment: Are you looking for numbers, or for not letters? 1-2-3 is not a number and neither is 1.2.3.4

Comment: - and . are fine. Just not alphabets

Answer (score 0):

Here, change the regex \S to be \s, notice the caps.

\S matches all but space, \s matches space.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\d+]\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[0-9\-.]+\s+
```

That will allow expressions with more than one decimal, and dashes inside them, vs just at the beginning.

You can use regexhero.net or www.regexplanet.com to test your regex expressions, they're very powerful tools.

Output from your given input would be the following matches:

```
12
1.2.3.4
```

**Edit, based on comment from OP**
This regex shouldn't require a space at the beginning.  If you need to match a number at the end of the line, it's probably simplest to just add a special case for it:

```
[0-9\-.]+\s|[0-9\-.]+$
```

Comment: Your solution works. Just one question before i mark it as correct answer. What if the text has space in start and no space at end, then the regex is not matching it. How to match for two conditions, when only space is there in front and not at the end and when space is there on both ends.

Comment: @sid,  Updated my answer to address your comment

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern to catch anything but alphabets

```
(?!\S*[a-zA-Z])\b([^a-zA-Z\s]+)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ3rJ2/8)